# Why won't the program print the sum of the array?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So I'm building a simple 8086 Assembly program that allows the user to input 4 digits, store them in an array and print out the sum of those digits (The sum must be a one digit number):

```
data segment

    i db ?
    array db 20 dup(?)
    sum db ?

ends

stack segment

    dw 128 dup(0)

ends

code segment

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov i, 0

Enter:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov bl, i
    mov bh, 0

    mov array[bx], al

    inc i
    cmp i, 4
    jne Enter

    mov sum, 0
    mov i, 0

Calc:
    mov bl, i
    mov bh, 0
    mov al, array[bx]

    add sum, al

    inc i
    cmp i, 4
    jne Calc

    mov dl, sum
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

ends
```

However when I input the numbers 1 1 2 5 instead of giving me 9 it gives me some random character.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to convert input from ascii and result to ascii.

Answer (score 3):

The DOS character input function gives you **characters**.
When you key in <kbd>1</kbd> DOS presents you with `AL='1'` meaning you get 49 where you might expect 1.
When you key in <kbd>2</kbd> DOS presents you with `AL='2'` meaning you get 50 where you might expect 2.
When you key in <kbd>5</kbd> DOS presents you with `AL='5'` meaning you get 53 where you might expect 5.
That's why we subtract 48 in these cases.

```
Enter:
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov bl, i
    mov bh, 0
    SUB AL, '0'        ;Same as SUB AL, 48
    mov array[bx], al
```

This way your array will contain the values 1, 1, 2, and 5 (No longer the characters '1', '1', '2', and '5')

Now you can safely do the additions, yielding 9.

Because *sum* now holds the value 9, but you need the character '9', you simple add 48 to do the conversion:

```
    mov dl, sum
    ADD DL, '0'        ;Same as ADD DL, 48
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
```