# How to reduce size of string arm assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm trying to make a assembly program to add two numbers, but when I type in the numbers it includes the \n at the end of the script meaning that when I do

```
add R3,R2,R1
```

it includes \n as a number
when I run strace it it shows that the program is printing two null terminators \0\0
[picture of the program running and the program running with strace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZja7.png)

the code is as follows

```
    .data
    keyin: .space 20
    num1: .space 2
    num2: .space 2
    num3: .space 3
    addmsg1: .ascii "enter a number: "
    addmsg2: .ascii "enter another number: "
    addmsg3: .ascii "the sum of those numbers are: "
    addcode: .ascii "add\n"

    .text
    .global _start:
_start:
    ldr R1,=addmsg1
    mov R2,#16
    bl print

    ldr R1,=num1
    mov R2,#2
    bl input

    ldr R1,=addmsg2
    mov R2,#22
    bl print

    ldr R1,=num2
    mov R2,#2
    bl input

    ldr R1,=num1
    ldr R1,[R1]
    ldr R2,=num2
    Ldr R2,[R2]
    add R3,R2,R1
    ldr R2,=num3
    str R3,[R2]
    ldr R1,=addmsg3
    mov R2,#30
    bl print

    ldr R1,=num3
    mov R2,#2
    bl print

print:
    mov R7,#4
    mov R0,#1
    SWI 0
    bx lr
    
input:
    ldr R1,=keyin
    mov R7,#3
    mov R0,#0
    SWI 0
    bx lr
```

I don't want to keep the \n when I type in the number but I have to accept it as part of the input otherwise if I typed 3 for the first number the \n would go into the second number as the input

I want to shorten the string to just one byte so that only the numbers are present

im uing rpi 4

arm V8-a
raspbian buster (for the syscalls)

any help would be welcome if you need more info just ask

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ldr` to load from something declared with `.space 2`. If you only care about the first byte, then why don't you use `ldrb` instead?

Comment: Also, your current way of calculating the sum is incorrect. You're dealing with characters, so you need to subtract `'0'` after the addition. Note that this will only work when both the inputs and the sum are single digits.

Comment: [Why won't the program print the sum of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53252729) explains why adding ASCII codes needs a `sub r0, #'0'` at the end.  But the code in that Q&A is for x86 so not an exact duplicate.

Comment: i tried doing the ldrb instead but the i got segmentation fault