# Why is my assembly output in letter position? (1+1=b)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I am using tasm. It is a simple program that reads the inputs from user and add the two numbers up. However, my output is displaying letters according to their letter position

For example, 3+5=h (8)
I want it to display in integer number.

```
.model small 
.stack 100h
.data 
input   db  13,10,"Enter a number : ","$"
output  db  13,10,"The sum is ","$"

.code
main    proc

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

;INPUT 1
mov ah,9
mov dx, offset input 
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al

;INPUT 2
mov ah,9
mov dx, offset input
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
add bl,al

;OUTPUT DISPLAY
mov ah,9
mov dx,offset output
int 21h

mov ah,2
mov dl,bl
int 21h

;END
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
main    endp
end main
```

Comment: Please don’t change the code in the question - it invalidates people’s answers and makes the question less useful for future readers. I’ve rolled back the edit.

Comment: Related: [Why won't the program print the sum of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53252525) has some example code, specifically `sub al, '0'` to turn an ASCII digit into an integer (assuming it actually *is* a digit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input digits are ASCII characters, so ‘1’ is actually 31h, for example. So when you calculate 1+1 your are getting 31h+31h=62h which is the ASCII character ‘b’.

To convert your input digits to their equivalent integer values you need to *subtract* ‘0’ (30h).

Conversely to output integer digits as ASCII characters you will need to *add* ‘0’.

Comment: AH tht makes sense! So i just add sub al,30h? I edited my post, if it is alright for you to look through? But my output now is giving me a weird symbol. 
(A heart shape in dosbox)

Comment: Re-read my answer above - you need to *subtract* 30h from your input digits and then *add* 30h when you want to output the result.